# How to change password for Full Disk Encryption?

Tags: password, encryption

When I installed Ubuntu, I opted to encrypt the whole OS.  I enter a password every time my computer boots up (note:  I'm not talking about the log-in screen -- I enter a password to get to that screen).  I'm not trying to remove this or anything, but I want to change the password.  Someone recommended that I check out the Gnome Disk Utility, which I did.  I can see my computer's hard drive, but, when I click on it, I'm only able to do anything related to encryption on one of the partitions.  I assumed this was the partition that I needed to change the password to, but, after I edited the password, I had to use the previous password upon the next boot.  I have no idea what I edited now (I removed the password from it because I have no clue what it is), and I still have no clue how to change the password that I want to change.  Hoping someone can help.